# fpga: choosing c++ to program fpga

Tags: c++, c, fpga

I keep hearing mostly from electrical engineers that C is used for fpga work.

What about C++? Are there any disadvantages to using C++? I would think that the parallelism desired when programming for hardware would be better served by C++ more than C, no?

Also what do I use after that to make compatible c++ with the hardware?

Comment: Are you referring to programming FPGS f/w using C, or accessing a running FPGA from a C application? In the latter case, I don't why C++ could not be used.

You may also want to take a look at SystemC. It's not really meant for programming FPGAs, although I suppose carefully written SystemC code could potentially be translated to HDL. On the other hand, if you write code using just SystemC constructs, you might as well write in VHDL or Verilog.

Answer (score 18):

I'm pretty sure that FPGAs are programmed either in VHDL or Verilog.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog

I know that Altera also offers some C to HDL translators. I doubt that they are usable for anything but tiny designs though.

Comment: I did some in AHDL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altera_Hardware_Description_Language) - but that's a similar language to VHDL.

Comment: +1. Just to clarify - writing C for FPGA just doesn't make sense. FPGAs are all about (parallel) digital signal processing and not sequential procedural programming. You can translate C to Verilog and then synthesize it into hardware, but it is like cutting your hair with a hatchet. Also, there are some soft CPU implementations for FPGAs (like Microblaze), and you can write a C program and run it on that soft CPU, but again - it has (almost) nothing to do with FPGA programming.

Comment: There is a free (online) C to verilog tool here http://www.c-to-verilog.com/online.html - results mostly only for interest, real hardware guy's don't generally use this sort of tool.

Answer (score 9):

By far and away the easiest way to program an FPGA is via LabView's FPGA module. However this also ties you into their hardware and software. Not a cheap solution, but certainly the fastest way to get your program in hardware without having to learn anything but LabVIEW.

Answer (score 7):

You can use C or C++ to program FPGAs but it requires some very expensive Highlevel Synthesis software.  CatapultC is a product from Mentor Graphics which allows you to write your algorithm in untimed C++.  It then synthesizes that C++ into RTL VHDL or Verilog.  But CatapultC sells for well over $100,000 so it's definitely not for hobbyists.  There's another product called ImpulseC which allows you to write C code which then gets synthesized into RTL, but I'm pretty sure that it only handles C not C++.  ImpulseC is about $2000.

For hobbyists, you're probably best off sticking with VHDL or Verilog to describe your design and then using the free tools from Xilinx or Altera to synthesize that code and program the FPGA.

Answer (score 5):

There is a big difference between compiling for CPUs and compiling for FPGAs. "Normal" compilers generate binary program code. The special FPGA compilers generate "hardware". There are compilers out there that turn some C-like code into "hardware". But it's not exactly C. It may be a C derivative extented with integer types of arbitrary bit lengths and is probably restricted to iteration and *non-recursive* function calls.

I am a big fan of C++ but even I see that many parts of it are just not appropriate for FPGAs: virtual functions, RTTI, exceptions. At least that's my impression. I didn't test those C-like FPGA compilers myself but a buddy of mine worked with them and it's supposedly a PITA.

Comment: "special FPGA compilers" covers several tools: synthesis; mapping; place and route

Answer (score 4):

They're probably using C to *interface* with the FPGA. When working with one in a design class, we used Verilog to program the FPGA and C in the attached Linux board. In that case, they're likely using C as it's easier to bang out a small program in C than in C++.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably talking about [SystemC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemC), which is a set of C++ classes and macros used mainly for (transaction-level) modeling, not for synthesis. The high-level model can then be used as a golden reference to verifiy the register transfer level (RTL) description, which is typically coded in VHDL or Verilog.

Comment: However, using SystemC requires that you use some fairly expensive synthesis tools - at least in the tens of thousands of dollars.  Definitely can't use the free FPGA vendor tools.

Comment: @aneccodeal I found creating a design with SystemC made it very easy to do a large set of simulations then I manually converted it to VHDL. Tedious, but the manual conversion took far less time than the initial C++ design and simulation and no need for expensive conversion synthesis tools.

Answer (score 3):

as some of you I'm a fan of C++. I think it would be great to use SystemC to work with fpga's. So looking for that I found the next page. Maybe it could interest some of you.

http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/~ljozwiak/education/5JJ70p/blocks/4/sc2fpgaflow.html

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is "behavioral synthesis", a compilation technique that allows to take sequential code as input (C, SystemC, C++) and generate automatically a FSM+Datapath pair in VHDL or Verilog, that can then be synthesized using regular Xilinx or Altera synthesizers.

To date, there are many "behavioral synthesizers" :

- CatapultC from Mentor Graphics allows you to use a big subset of C and also C++
- Cynthesizer from Forte Design System (systemC based) [**edit 2015**: now Cadence]
- for FPGA, ImpulseC seems quite mature
- [**edit 2015**] for Xilinx FPGA : Vivado-HLS

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Two that I can think of off the top of my head:  C++ is much more complicated to write compilers (in this case HDL translators) for and has too many features that just would not be useful in such low level programming as fpga programming calls for.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said most FPGA's are designed using [VHDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl) or [Verilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog). I have also seen [PALASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PALASM) used several years ago for small designs. The design is a logic description that is converted to settings that configure the FPGA. Verilog is based on c so knowing c will help with learning verilog however FPGAs are by nature parallel so even though the syntax might look similar not much else translates.

Comment: PALASM is very obsolete (used in 1980's os so).

Answer (score 1):

They might be talking about a programming language like Handel-C, which is some kind of C dialect, targeted for hardware programming.  Handel-C can be directly or indirectly compiled to HDL, which in turn creates an FPGA configuration (i.e., the "program" on an FPGA).

Although VHDL and Verilog are much harder to learn, I suggest you start right away. When you're doing FPGA-related stuff, you're usually interested in efficiency. Handel-C will most likely make less efficient code than the code that you can write by hand (in VHDL or Verilog).

Edit: There's no C++ variant of Handel-C or related compilers I have ever head of.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use a soft processor running on the FPGA and code in C from there (NIOS from Altera, Microblaze from Xilinx etc).
2. SOC FPGA using OpenCL to interface with the FPGA from the ARM processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C/C++ to program FPGAs. Xilinx has SDSoC, an eclipse based tool to program your FPGAs using C/C++. This basically builds hardware accelerator for part of code flagged to be synthesized. This assumes ARM+FPGA based zynq devices, host code is running on ARM

There is another flow SDAccel for PC based solution. With host code on X86 & accelerator on FPGA connected to your PCIe slot.

Answer (score 0):

FPGA code describes hardware. What that means is you design a digital system and then use code to "describe" the hardware to the compiler. This is mainly done in VHDL or Verilog.

Modern compilers provide inerfaces between software and hardware platforms to let you write C code that can be run on FPGAs. Its not really code that will be uploaded to the FPGA but merely lets the compiler make code for the FPGA based on your C code. For an optimal system, there will need to be a Hardware Engineer who can make changes to the compiler generated code. 
Here's a nice article on the issue: https://www.eetimes.com/c-language-techniques-for-fpga-acceleration-of-embedded-software/#

There are some programs like Intel Monitor Program which let you run C code on FPGAs but what it does is create a 'Computer' using the Microprocessor already on Chip to let you see how the code works. Its more of a learning tool.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this has been said yet (I didn't read all the responses) but it is a possibility that what you are hearing is a running software in a soft core... For instance Altera has Nios II which can run a linux kernel (uCLinux) which will allow some pre-loaded C programs to run on that soft core which in turn communicates with the FPGA. So an FPGA will still be programmed with VHDL/Verilog for the hardware side, then whatever data it holds could be accessible to a small app running on the OS in the soft core. I'm sure C++ would be allowed so long as uCLinux/whatever kernel is running supports the language.

~doddy

Answer (score -2):

You usually get a larger standard library with C++ and with C, and C is closer to the way that the hardware operates, i.e. easier for electrical engineers.